# How to escape a single quote

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, fetch

I'm using the `pg_query_params` function to add values in my table `vmobjects` in my `addvm.php` page.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO vmobjects(guid, ipaddress, username, password, hostid, vmname, guestostype) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6,

$7)";
        $result = pg_query_params($conn, $query, array($guid, $ip, $username, $password, $hostid, $name, strtolower($os)));
```

Now I'm using `pg_fetch_array` for fetch the row in an array.

I'm using this query:

```
$query = "select vmname, guid, hostid, guestosname from vmobjects";

AddLog("infrastructure.php", "Query: ".$query, ERR_DEBUG_LOW);
$result = pg_query($conn, $query);
$no_records = pg_num_rows($result);
$j = $no_records;
$i = 0;
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row[3] == "")
    {
        $vmobj_Array[$i] = $row[0] . '***' . $row[1] . '***' . $row[2];
    }
    else
    {
        $vmobj_Array[$i] = $row[0] . ' ( ' . $row[3] . ' )' . '***' . $row[1] . '***' . $row[2];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But it is working only for a simple string like `james, helton, discovere`, not for `j'ames, h'elton, d'iscovere`.

Actually I want to fetch the row in *both* formats.

Comment: Not quite sure what your issue is: are you saying you can't **insert** those values, or you can't **retrieve** those values? What error do you get?

Comment: @ Femi:i m inserting those values in my table row j'ames, h'elton, d'iscovere  but not able to fetch them.

Comment: i m able to fetch only james, helton, discovere in this format

Comment: Quite odd: can you confirm they actually ARE in the database using the `psql` client? And what error do you get when you try and fetch the row?

Comment: actualy when i add like j'ames in my table then it adds , but when i want to fetch then it isn't, i m using pg_query_params i think this is the isue but withour this all escape characters r not posible to insert

Comment: i know that it is only the array isue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row[3] == "")
    {

        $vmobj_Array[$i] = htmlentities($row[0], ENT_QUOTES) . "***" . $row[1] . "***" . $row[2];
    }
    else
    {

        $vmobj_Array[$i] = htmlentities($row[0], ENT_QUOTES) . "***" . $row[1] . "***" . $row[2];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per  [how to encode single  quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067113/how-to-encode-single-quotes) , `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);` or `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);` should do the trick where $str should be replaced by the variable or string you want to escape (e.g., `$row[0]`). If you just want to add it, all you need to do is add it: `print "Here's an apostrophe &#039;";`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to fetch the values to get `both`:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_BOTH)){
```

Also, your queries are different: in the `INSERT` you are inserting `guestostype`, but you are selecting `guestosname` in the SELECT. I'm guessing your query is simply not returning any values because you are asking for a row that doesn't exist, but verify with `psql` that all the data is in the table.

Comment: ohhhh guestostype actualy this is the type of os ... in insert time we r asking about which os u used !! while when somone select then guestosname select not an isue

Comment: i only want to fetch this value ' ' ''' '''' like F'emi B'ro

Comment: Well, your INSERT statement does not have `guestosname`, so when you SELECT from the same row where does it come from? Can you show the table definition?

Comment: Table "public.vmobjects"
   Column    |          Type          | Modifiers
-------------+------------------------+-----------
 guid        | character varying(36)  | not null
 ipaddress   | character varying(32)  | not null
 username    | character varying(32)  |
 password    | character varying(32)  |
 hostid      | character varying(36)  | not null
 vmname      | character varying(124) | not null
 guestostype | character varying(32)  |
 guestosname | character varying(128) |

Comment: i m using bot but i don't want to fetch guestostype, thats why i m not using this.

Comment: Oh ok. Well, I guess your INSERT statement is not working, because the SELECT statement should definitely work. Try also inserting a value into `guestosname` and see if that helps.

Comment: my INSERT statement is  working man thats why i m able to insert values like james, helton, discovere

Comment: i m able to insert any data except this '

Comment: Ah. Is it also working for j'ames, h'elton and d'iscovere? If you insert those values can you see them with `psql`?

Comment: my table take those values j'ames, h'elton, d'iscovere  but nothing to display

Comment: i m using pg_query_params function nd it inserts all values '~!@#$%^&*()_+=-`{}|\][:"';<>?/.,'

Comment: i m able to see those values except '

Comment: So you CAN NOT see those values in `psql`?

Comment: @Femi:) i m unable to see only '

Comment: Ah, so if `psql` does not see any values with a single quote in them, so this means your INSERT doesn't work for values with a single quote, right? Because running `SELECT * FROM vmobjects` in `psql` should return all values.

Comment: @ Femi:) when i use this then nothing to display SELECT * FROM vmobjects sry its not right

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test program which appears to be more or less a program which executes the key functionality described above.  It seems to work just fine.  Can you explain how your program differs from this test program or provide a test program of your own?

```
<?php
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost");
$result = pg_exec($conn,"drop table tvmobjects cascade;");
$result = pg_exec($conn,"create table tvmobjects (guid text not null, ipaddress text not null, username text not null, password text, hostid text not null, vmname text not null, guestostype text, guestosname text);");

function add_user($conn,$guid,$ip,$username,$password,$hostid,$name,$os)
{
  $query = "INSERT INTO tvmobjects(guid,ipaddress,username,password,hostid,vmname,guestostype) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)";
  $result = pg_query_params($conn,$query,array($guid,$ip,$username,$password,$hostid,$name,strtolower($os)));
  $no_records=pg_num_rows($result);
  echo "Got $no_records in insert of $username\n";
}

add_user($conn,"james","1.2.3.4","james","semaj", "jamesid", "jamesvm", "jamesostype");
add_user($conn,"j'ames","1.2.3.5","j'ames","semaj", "j'amesid", "j'amesvm", "j'amesostype");

$query= "select vmname,guid,hostid,guestosname from tvmobjects";
$result = pg_query($conn,$query);
$no_records=pg_num_rows($result);
$j=$no_records;
$i=0;
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($row[3]=="")
  {
    echo $row[0].'***'.$row[1].'***'.$row[2]."\n";
  }
  else
  {
    echo $row[0].' ( '.$row[3].' )'.'***'.$row[1].'***'.$row[2]."\n";
  }
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Running this for me generates:

```
Got 0 in insert of james
Got 0 in insert of j'ames
jamesvm***james***jamesid
j'amesvm***j'ames***j'amesid
```

As previously pointed out, you are not inserting guestosname when you insert the record, so likewise the output shown here doesn't have the (guestosname) annotation.  But the insert and select seems to work like a champ so it is not clear what is wrong.