#  how to encode single  quotes

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I want to know how i use htmlentities  `•&#039; for '` in my code ? 
[How to escape single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058523/how-to-escape-single-quote)

hows `apostrophe`  work in `IE`

```
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row[3]=="")
    {

        $vmobj_Array[$i]=$row[0]."***".$row[1]."***".$row[2];
    }
    else
    {
        $vmobj_Array[$i]=$row[0].' ( '.$row[3].' )'."***".$row[1]."***".$row[2];

    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Use search and replace in your editor?

Comment: @Rasika:)&apos; (does not work in IE) apostrophe

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you trying to find out where you have use &#039; in your code or you want it to be replaced so that it displays properly in all browsers?

Comment: @ Rasika:) i want to displays properly in all browsers? right now i m unable to display

Comment: Please show us what you are including. `&#039;` should work fine in all browsers.

Comment: Can you display what "View->Source" (IE) or "View->Page Source" (FF) shows in your browser?

Comment: @ tandu:) it display my table rows

Comment: @ brettz9:)i don't no how to include &#039; for escape single quote?

Comment: `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);` or `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);` should do the trick where `$str` should be replaced by the variable or string you want to escape (e.g., `$row[0]`). If you just want to add it, all you need to do is add it:  `print "Here's an apostrophe &#039;";`

Comment: @brettz9 :) can u add this in my question <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058523/how-to-escape-single-quote">How to escape single quote</a>

Comment: @brettz9:)actualy i want to select ur ans as best ans .. rockin stackoverflow

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think every question should have an answer, so I'm posting here as well. Feel free to accept the answer someone else posted there just now.

`htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);` or `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);` should do the trick where $str should be replaced by the variable or string you want to escape (e.g., `$row[0]`). If you just want to add it, all you need to do is add it: `print "Here's an apostrophe &#039;";`

Comment: Not works for me, not shows correctly in Android or IOS